# Should create another Jpanel?

Tags: java

I have one Mediator.java which do all the functions. And there is RecordGenerationJPanel.java to save the information of a record.NewApplicationJPanel.java is main screen and when I click jbtnGenerate in it, it will show RecordGenerationJPanel and do the showGern method in Mediator class.

All the methods have done by another developer and I have asked to make a new class which will function like showGern method. New showGern class should do some combo box disabled and it also include new text field. But it will be invoked only a checkbox in main screen(NewApplicationJPanel) is checked. Otherwise, it will call the original showGern Method.

Do I need to create another RecordGenerationJPanel? Or, can I do it in same RecordGenerationJPanel? If it's same, how should I do to show different enabling or disabling and hiding some text field according to condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, if RecordGenerationJPanel and the requested new class share some attributes and methods, those attributes and methods should be in one class and used by both. So if theres's a future change requirement of a bug fix that affects those common parts, you just have to do it once and both panels benefit from the single fix.

In your case, I'd really copy the existing RecordGenerationJPanel to a new class and modify it to meet you requirements.

If it works, you can start a refactoring and extract the common parts to a new class.

Comment: In this case, after copying the existing class to a new class and modifying it, should I change the components name in new class not to be same with the original class? Or can I use the same name in both classes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Names should reflect the purpose of a field or method. If the names from the other class make sense for your class, then keep them. Technically, there's no need to choose different names. Ask your team or supervisor if they have any other naming conventions (they may have some!)

Answer (score 0):

You can add new "checkbox" (as described in your question) to old JPanel. And show/Hide/enable/disable components based on state of checkbox. Also which method to call depends on state of this checkbox.

You can enable/disable components by implementing ActionListener and attaching it to Checkbox.

```
   JCheckBox cb1 = new JCheckBox("Check Box 1")    
   cb1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

           //enable disable components if checkbox is selected

           //enable disable components if checkbox is not selected

      }
    });
```

Hope this helps.